# magento setup upgrade error: field can't be empty

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade

After: php-cli bin/magento setup:upgrade

Getting see image:
[image]

Anyone an idea?

Comment: This happens because the title and media attributes are read from the theme.xml and the version and parent are read from the composer.json.

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

Answer (score 2):

**This issue raised due to Theme**

As per as,your shared picture, *you have `installed Codazon Fastest/Any Codazon theme` at your system*.

***This theme must have any issue and issue arise  as Magento does not validated that theme***

See at `Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\Validator`  method  _`setTitleValidators`.

May be *any theme of codazon* does **not define theme name** **`theme.xml`**.

***Or May be you have  an issue in composer.json  of theme or Codazon module***

See magento some details at https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/840

Answer (score 1):

Check your SQL files. May be missing default value for the column.

Answer (score 1):

Few steps to solve your above problem:-

1.) Check your: `app/design/frontend/Vendor/yourtheme/theme.xml` and check if it has got `<title></title>` tag has got a value and it is not empty

2.) Clear your `var/` and `generation/` or `generated/` folder and run your `setup:upgrade` again.

3.) Check if your database has entry for that particular theme or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have indeed delete the themes I don't use from the FTP and now it works, I think same works for SQL, so with this advice I came to this solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error can have multiple causes, as @amit-bera mentions: a theme.xml file can have an empty title-field, or (as in my case) a row in the 'theme'-table within your database has an empty value within the 'theme_title' column.

Answer (score 0):

check if there is any directories that may have been mistakenly created by you in the Theme Directory Structure
even an empty directory will be thought as a theme by magento structure and since this empty directory does not have any theme.xml in it, then it will throw an error

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help someone, but in my case, the problem was I had inherited a slightly mangled database and there was a record in the theme table that had a theme with no title. Deleted that record to resolve the problem.

```
DELETE FROM theme WHERE title IS NULL;
```

... or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue while installing the Fastest Codazon. To fix this issue check the theme.xml and composer.json files. some themes don't have all the files so added teh fashion theme from the codazon theme. its works properly.