# ERROR Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: Field title can't be empty in Model/Theme.php:337

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, error, installation, linux

I have this problem installing Magento2, is stopped at 51%.

I checked:

- Permissions => chmod 777
- Composer Installation
- DB

Also I tried with those Solutions:

- [magento setup upgrade error: field can't be empty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181387/magento-setup-upgrade-error-field-cant-be-empty)
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1870

Info:

- PHP 7.0.33 (cli)
- Magento CLI version 2.2.1
- CentOS release 6.9 (Final)
- mysqld 5.7.24

**Please help**

This is the log of the Magento Installation :

```
Module 'Magento_Theme':
    Installing data... 
    [ERROR] Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: Field title can't be empty in /var/www/vhosts/lcdtcorp.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/Theme.php:337
    Stack trace:
    #0 /var/www/vhosts/lcdtcorp.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/Theme.php(349): Magento\Theme\Model\Theme->_validate()
    #1 /var/www/vhosts/lcdtcorp.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/AbstractDb.php(406): Magento\Theme\Model\Theme->beforeSave()
    #2 /var/www/vhosts/lcdtcorp.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(647): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb->save(Object(Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Data))
    #3 /var/www/vhosts/lcdtcorp.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/Theme/Registration.php(114): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->save()
    #4 /var/www/vhosts/lcdtcorp.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/Theme/Registration.php(73): Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Registration->_registerThemeRecursively(Object(Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Data))
    #5 /var/www/vhosts/lcdtcorp.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-theme/Setup/InstallData.php(39): Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Registration->register()
    #6 /var/www/vhosts/lcdtcorp.com/httpdocs/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(867): Magento\Theme\Setup\InstallData->install(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), Object(Magento\Setup\Model\ModuleContext))
    #7 /var/www/vhosts/lcdtcorp.com/httpdocs/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(791): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), 'data')
    #8 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures()
    #9 /var/www/vhosts/lcdtcorp.com/httpdocs/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(342): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #10 /var/www/vhosts/lcdtcorp.com/httpdocs/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Controller/Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array)
    #11 /var/www/vhosts/lcdtcorp.com/httpdocs/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(82): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction()
    #12 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #13 /var/www/vhosts/lcdtcorp.com/httpdocs/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #14 /var/www/vhosts/lcdtcorp.com/httpdocs/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(211): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
    #15 /var/www/vhosts/lcdtcorp.com/httpdocs/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
    #16 /var/www/vhosts/lcdtcorp.com/httpdocs/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(93): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
    #17 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #18 /var/www/vhosts/lcdtcorp.com/httpdocs/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #19 /var/www/vhosts/lcdtcorp.com/httpdocs/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(211): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
    #20 /var/www/vhosts/lcdtcorp.com/httpdocs/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(314): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
    #21 /var/www/vhosts/lcdtcorp.com/httpdocs/setup/index.php(35): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
    #22 {main}
```